# How to restart ceilometer service

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I changed pulling intervals in `/etc/ceilometer/pipeline.yaml` file from 600 to 60 and can't make the service to use new values. I restarted everything that relates to ceilometer in openstack-status command, but that did not work. Can somebody tell me the proper way how to do it?

I am using Openstack Liberty on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
root@OS1:~# openstack service list
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------+
| ID                               | Name       | Type          |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------+
| 056fcccaad5c4991a8a0da199ed1d737 | cinderv2   | volumev2      |
| 483a0cd1ba79430690a8960ae3d40222 | glance     | image         |
| 5c704fc9253e4c15895589eb19fab2ac | keystone   | identity      |
| 92bfcfb417314e80a43e6e7d4d21f99b | nova       | compute       |
| a7a3809d73674d3da3fbe8030b47055a | horizon    | dashboard     |
| c21b5e3c9d68417cb11df60d72f9bb58 | heat       | orchestration |
| c7030edb082346328a715b00098b974a | neutron    | network       |
| d331f5360e2b4d3a854e7f47107a9421 | ec2        | ec2           |
| f0a22f827bed43dbbc43822abfc3e3e0 | ceilometer | metering      |
+----------------------------------+------------+---------------+

root@OS11:~# openstack-status
.
.
.
== Ceilometer services ==
ceilometer-api:               active
ceilometer-agent-central:     active
ceilometer-agent-compute:     inactive (disabled on boot)
ceilometer-collector:         active
ceilometer-alarm-notifier:    active
ceilometer-alarm-evaluator:   active
ceilometer-agent-notification:active
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ceilometer-agent-compute service` is disabled, you just need to restart `ceilometer-agent-central` service on the node you have modified the config file.

```
sudo service ceilometer-agent-central restart
```

You might want to auto reload pipelines after you modify it, for that, you can set `refresh_pipeline_cfg=True` and a proper time for `pipeline_polling_interval` such as 120 seconds in `/etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf`.

Note, be careful when you enable auto reload, and only save pipeline config file after you are sure about the content is right (otherwise it might lose 1 polling period data)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to restart `ceilometer-agent-notification` service because this service is responsible for transforming the data into samples in the ceilometer database.

Thus, `systemctl restart ceilometer-agent-notification.service` will help along with restarting other services.